# Resizeable background for 1 page layout with multiple sections

Tags: jquery, css

I have a horizontal site with 8 sections all requiring a full background image that needs to re-size with the browser.
Please look at: http://www.dancephotography.net.au/test1.htm

Be gentle... I'm a novice with no flash knowledge. This is an unfinished design that will become a template for other pages.

Comment: welcome to SO. I'd suggest you be a little more specific with your question and post any relevant starter code if you have any.  The more detail you can provide, the more people will be able to help you.  As it is, it's difficult to know what exactly you're asking in your question.

Comment: @nmc I think she's asking about how she can make her background resize when the browser is resized...

Comment: Yes thats it... resize proportionally... a different background for each container on the page (8) XX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@belinda; you can dot it with `css3 cover` property

```
.wrap {
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

& for IE you can you `FILTER`

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

or you can use `100%` like this.

```
.wrap {
            background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: 100%;
            -moz-background-size: 100%;
            -o-background-size: 100%;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
```

it's stretch the image according to the heigfht & width of the div. 
**FOR MORE CHECK THIS LINK** http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: For the Css cover property as above (.wrap) do I place this under the CSS property for each of the 8 sections on the page? ie home- bio-interactive-printidentity etc

Comment: yup you can place cover property for each of the 8 sections on the page

Comment: What  is the .wrap? A new attribute for each section? Do I add that to the CSS for this page?

Comment: .wrap; is a background container & as per your website you have to put it in each page with different background class which get the images in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `div` with an `img` underneath everything would be a lot easier, as you could set a maximum/minimum width and or height so that the image doesn't distort too awkwardly.

This solution is not CSS3 specific, so any browser should behave the same way. I've typed up an example for you which can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/Qzcnn/.

Comment: Thanks so much for this I really appreciate your time. I am looking for resize that is in proportion.